# Get User in Laravel 5.4 Controller constructor

Tags: laravel-5, constructor, controller

I have Laravel 5.4 Base Controller which should share along children Controllers some common data depending on current Authenticated user.

I was Trying to get it like

```
public function __construct(ValidationFactory $validation)
{
    $this->middleware(array('auth', 'lockscreen'));
    var_dump(\Auth::user());
    die;  
}
```

this do not works.

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: this will return null, as I understand mainly because of middleware

Comment: `var_dump(\Auth::user();` misses a `)`

Comment: this is a typo in here, otherwise would dump some error and not null

Comment: @fefe That's a change introduced in 5.3. The recommended workaround is to use a closure middleware ([see docs for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)).

Comment: ah ok thanks! I just do not know than how would I pass in this case the required middlewares

Comment: Something like this should work: 
```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware( [ 'auth', 'lockscreen', function ($request, $next) {
        // set the user and anything else you might need
        $this->user = $request->user();

        return $next($request);
    } ] );
}
```

Comment: P.S. Sorry for the formatting. It appears comments here don't support the block syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private $userId;

public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->userId = Auth::user()->id;
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried using this. This does not work trying to access the variable outside middleware definition returns null.